# Multiple threads in Python server

Tags: python, multithreading

I am building for school a little Python server script, that has to read a file and send it to the client.

Now, I need the server to answer to multiple requests from clients at same time. At this moment it will only accept 1 client... and just after the client is answered, it moves to the next.

My teacher told me to use multiple processes/threads to achieve that. I am new to Python so I have no idea how to manage this.

How can I do that?

Here is my code:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
s.bind((host,port)) 
s.listen(backlog) 
while 1:
    print "server ready, waiting..."
    client, address = s.accept() 
    print "recvd client", address 
    data = client.recv(size) 
    if data:

        parametro_data = data.split(' ')
        if(parametro_data[0] == '/GET'):

            theFile = parametro_data[1].replace('\r\n','')

            if os.path.isfile(theFile):
                f = open(theFile, 'r')
                for line in f:
                    client.send(line)
                f.close()
            else:
                client.send("File not exists")

    client.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you should do is to keep the time the server thread is captured with a single request (i.e. after the `s.accept()` line returns) to a minimum. A common way to do that is to spawn a thread directly after that which then handles the request spearately. Then you can return to waiting for the next request (i.e. `accept` again) directly without being paused by the still ongoing handling which happens in the other thread.

I’d also suggest you to look into the [socketserver](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html) module, as that already gives you exactly that in a higher level. You just define a handler for the connections, then create the server with that handler, and make the server [“serve forever”](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html#SocketServer.BaseServer.serve_forever).

Comment: Should I base myself on this example or is there something more simple? http://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html#asynchronous-mixins

Comment: That example is fine, but note that there is also the client code in it; which you won’t need, and which makes running the server in a thread required too. You just need to run `server.serve_forever()` after creating the `ThreadedTCPServer`.

Answer (score 0):

To handle this in the model you have describe you will take out the code where you do the actual file sending and encapsulate this inside of a thread.

```
class HandleClient( threading.Thread ):
 def __init__( self, clientSocket, file_to_read ):
  ...setting up the thread object...
 def run( self ):
  ...sending code...
```

This will send the file so that your main acceptance thread will be able to handle other clients.

So, your client flow would be as follows:

new client connection -> accept the connection -> create the new thread object and call the `start()` method -> the thread will send the file to this client and then close the connection.

[Threading Documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html)

[threading.Thread Documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects)

I would also look into a thread pool as you can only have so many threads at once before it does not give you any benefit or if possible a framework that provides the server functionality and you just have to write the business logic, in your case the sending of the file.